# React native with connect helper from redux doesn't re-render when state change?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I used `reactJS` and i know that a component that is wrapped with `connect` helper that listens to specific `reducer` when its `reducer's state` changes it causes the component to `re-render`.

I don't know why same procedure doesn't work for `react-native`, i tested my `action creators` as well as `reducers` and checked hundred percent that they return new `state`, And when i checked `componentWillRecieveProps` i found that the new state is returned correctly and the component doesn't re-render.

---

**Reducer**

```
const INITIAL = {
  isSigned: null
}

export default (state = INITIAL, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case SIGNED_IN : return {...state, isSigned: true};
    case LOGGED_OUT: return {...state, isSigned: false};
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';


class Loading extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  componentDidMount(){

    this.props.checkSigned();

     switch(this.props.isSigned){
       case null  : return;
       case false : this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
       case true  : this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
     }
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({signed}) => {
  const {isSigned} = signed;
  return {
    isSigned
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Loading);
```

**Actions**

```
export const SIGNED_IN = 'SIGNED_IN';
export const LOGGED_OUT = 'LOGGED_OUT';

//Action Creators

export const checkSigned = () => async dispatch => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fb_token');
     if(token){
       dispatch({type: SIGNED_IN})
     }
    dispatch({type: LOGGED_OUT})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `bindActionCreators` to dispatch your actions as props

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isSigned: state.isSigned
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Loading);
```

// In actions, you need to fix action code

```
export const checkSigned = () => async dispatch => {
let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fb_token');
 if(token){
   dispatch({type: SIGNED_IN});
 } else {
    dispatch({type: LOGGED_OUT});
 }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it is not true even though i tried it and it is not working. bindActionCreators is an alternative way to dispatch actions, which means the problem still the same

Comment: Updated answer @Dodz

Comment: Actually i don't have problems with actions nor reducers, and i mentioned that my reducers working correctly as well as returning a new valid state with the updated one, but my component doesn't re-render

Comment: You don't have state.signed i.e. `{signed}` that's why it will always be `undefiend` and will not rerender component

Comment: signed is the name of the reducer, combineReducers({ signed })

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're running your state change logic in `componentDidMount`. `componentDidMount` doesn't run when your component re-renders, but `componentDidUpdate` does. Put your logic there.

Comment: Its true, but also changing to `componentDidUpdate` doesn't change anything. also i tried to put `console.log` inside render function and found out it is only called once which means the component don't re render on state change